# XAML Gridview to add an item directly

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I successfully coded an XAML Gridview to show list of items.

However, I want to add an [+(ADD ITEM)] button at the end of the Gridview.

[image]

The ADD button has should have a custom template (at least a default button) which is different from the content item.

My XAML source is below:

```
<GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Padding="116,136,116,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSource}}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                        <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetDate}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10" FontSize="12"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <!--
            Something like that..
            <Button Content="+" x:Name="btnAdd" /> 
            -->
        </GridView>
```

And, how can I add a ADD button(grid item) to XAML? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a `DataTemplateSelector`, basically what you need to do is :

1. define another class that will represent the GridView "addItem"

   ```
   public class GridItem
   {
     public String Subject { get; set; }
     public String TargetDate { get; set; }
   }

   public class AddGridItem : GridItem
   {
     public bool IsGridItem { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure that your `GridView`'s `ItemSource` collection has always an `AddGridItem` in it

   ```
   private ObservableCollection<GridItem> _gridItems  =new ObservableCollection<GridItem>()
   {
       new GridItem()
       {
           Subject = "Subject1",
           TargetDate = "TargetDate"
       },new GridItem()
       {
           Subject = "Subject2",
           TargetDate = "TargetDate"
       },new GridItem()
       {
           Subject = "Subject3",
           TargetDate = "TargetDate"
       },new AddGridItem()
       {
           IsGridItem = true
       }
   };


   public ObservableCollection<GridItem> GridItems
   {
       get
       {
           return _gridItems;
       }

       set
       {
           if (_gridItems == value)
           {
               return;
           }

           _gridItems = value;                
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a `DataTemplateSelector` class that will return the appropriate `DataTemplate` based on the Item type

   ```
   public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
   {
     public DataTemplate RegularTemplate { get; set; }
     public DataTemplate AddTemplate { get; set; }

     protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item,
                                                      DependencyObject container)
     {
        if (item is AddGridItem)
           return AddTemplate;
        if (item is GridItem)
           return RegularTemplate;           
        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
     }
   }
   ```
4. Define your dataTempaltes and a `DataTemplateSelector` as `staticresources` to use them in your `GridView`

   ```
   <Page.Resources>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="RegularTemplate">
       <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
           <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White">
               <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="LightSkyBlue">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetDate}"  Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10" FontSize="12"/>
               </StackPanel>
           </Border>
       </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="AddItemTemplate">
       <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Background="DodgerBlue">
           <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE0B6;" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
       </Border>
     </DataTemplate>
     <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector"
      RegularTemplate="{StaticResource RegularTemplate}"
     AddTemplate="{StaticResource AddItemTemplate}">
     </local:MyDataTemplateSelector>
   </Page.Resources>
   <Grid>
     <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}">            
     </GridView>
   </Grid>
   ```

Comment: Great! It looks somewhat complicated yet it would be the simplest one. Thanks.